# Creating report in Word from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a small problem. When I create a document from Excel to word from a sheet in Excel the Sheet needs to be unhidden. How can I Create this report if I want to "hide" this sheet.

code:

```
    Sub Createrapport()

Dim UserName As String
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Var vänligen och ange ditt namn nedan:")
If UserName = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else
Sheets("Rapport").Range("I1").Value = UserName
End If


    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object


    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets("Rapport").Activate
    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdApp.Visible = True


    'sidhuvud
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I4").Text
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0

    'sidnummer
    'Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True


    '***** copy image from cell B1 in Excel
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("H11:M41").Copy
    '***** past image at the current position in Word
    wdApp.Selection.Paste


Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E81")

rng.Copy

   With wd.Range
        .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
        .Collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
   End With


End Sub
```

**Edited version**

```
 Sub Createrapport()

Dim UserName As String
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Var vänligen och ange ditt namn nedan:")
If UserName = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else
Sheets("Rapport").Range("I1").Value = UserName
End If


    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object


    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets("Rapport").Activate
    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdApp.Visible = True


    'sidhuvud
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I4").Text
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0

    'sidnummer
    'Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True

    '***** copy image from cell H11:M411 in Excel
    Worksheets("Rapport").Range("H11:M41").Copy
    '***** past image at the current position in Word
    wdApp.Selection.Paste


Set rng = Worksheets("Rapport").Range("A1:E81")

rng.Copy

   With wd.Range
        .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
        .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
   End With


End Sub
```

**2nd EDIT**

```
  Sub Createrapport()

Dim UserName As String
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="Var vänligen och ange ditt namn nedan:")
If UserName = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else
Sheets("Rapport").Range("I1").Value = UserName
End If


    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wd As Object


    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Sheets("Rapport").Activate
    Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
    wdApp.Visible = True


    'sidhuvud
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 9
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport").Range("I4").Text
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0



    'sidnummer
    'Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  ", PreserveFormatting:=True

    '***** copy image from cell H11:M411 in Excel
    Worksheets("Rapport").Range("H11:M41").Copy
    '***** past image at the current position in Word
    wdApp.Selection.Paste


Set rng = Worksheets("Rapport").Range("A1:E100")

rng.Copy

   With wd.Range
        .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .InsertParagraphAfter                   'Lägg till rad
        .collapse Direction:=0                  'Slutet av dokumentet
        .PasteSpecial False, False, True        'Pasta som Enhanced Metafile
   End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("H11:M41").Copy
```

The sheet won't be active if it is hidden. You can refer to the sheet by name directly:

```
Worksheets("Rapport").Range("H11:M41").Copy
```

According to MS copying should work from a hidden worksheet. It works in Excel, but isn't reliable when pasting to other Office applications. I would unhide, and then hide, the worksheet.

---

The updated code (in the OP) still refers to `ActiveSheet`, which won't be Rapport, so the clipboard content will probably be empty. This

```
wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I4").Text
```

should be

```
wdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport").Range("I4").Text
```

However, the username is in I1, not I4.

Within Word you cannot use `Paste` on its own, with Excel data. You need to use one of several `PasteSpecial` methods, such as:

```
wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject, Placement _
    :=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Record a Macro in Word to discover the other PasteSpecial options.

Recording a Macro in Word, and just using the default Paste, gives this code:

```
    wdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

Comment: Hey Andy, thank you for your answer. I have tried and modified the code ( see above) according to your sudgestions, but it still doesn't seem to work when the sheet "rapport" is hidden. Could you please take a look at the code and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RinorM what exactly isn't working, do you get some sort of an error message? If so, on what line?

Comment: Yes, we need these details. But you also still have `Sheets("Rapport").Activate` in your code. It doesn't look like you need this line, delete it.

Comment: What happens when I run the macro is that it shows up a blank word page and none of the information has been copied and pasted into the word-document. If i take away the **Sheets("Rapport").Activate** then the header created inside of the word document gets removed. Thank you.

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Comment: This is getting really confusing, I don't know what more to change in the code for the document to appear when the sheet is hidden. I pasted the edited code one more time. I'm kind of new to VBA as you can see. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Copying form a hidden worksheet is supposed to work (according to the documentation) but it doesn't seem to work reliably between Office applications. I would unhide it, and then hide it again afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Andy. Thing is I am creating a software for a company. It wouldn't be so good to have alot of open sheets there.

Comment: If you turn off ScreenUpdating, unhide and then hide they would be none the wiser. It's up to you though. Good luck.